# Indexing hash with Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a cache store as follows

For every user in the system, his match with every item in the inventory.

```
user1_id => {item1_id => 90, item2_id => 85, item3_id => 75}
user2_id => {item1_id => 70, item2_id => 85, item3_id => 95}
```

Currently, the above hash is being computed and stored in **MongoDB**.

**Requirement:** when the user visits the inventory listing page, I want all the items to be listed in order of his match.

For user_1,
it should be in the order of item1, item2, item3

For user_2,
it should be in the order of item3, item2, item1.

What is the best way to index this in sphinx, so that i can order it with sphinx something like,

```
Item.search("", :with => {:user_reference => user1_id}, :order => "item_match DESC")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this with **sphinx** would be with payload fields.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-joined-field

have absolutely no idea how would deploy that via thinking-sphinx/ruby.

Would rather than storing the 'user_reference' in a multi-value attribute. Store in a field as 'fake keywords'. When get a match, they payload woudl affect the overall weight. Would probably need to use really high values to make the computed values a lot higher than normal document weights (as need to use SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25 ) 
It's used for a different purpose, but the fake keywords idea is mentioned here:
http://sphinxsearch.com/info/faq/#filter-or